# HTML and Javascript, window.prompt

Tags: javascript, html

Very new to javascript and html-type stuff. I wanted to just make a quick example using input from a user and outputting it into a table. I'm having trouble getting the window prompt to actually come up though. I imagine there is somethign very obvious that I am doing wrong but I'm not currently seeing it...I am taking a class in school but this isn't a homework assignment, just exercises I am doing on my own.

Is this something with the while loop? Any suggestions as to how I should keep prompting the user until they state otherwise?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mileage Record</title>
<style type = "text/css">
    table {
        width:300px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        background-color:lightblue;
        }
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 4px;
        }
    th {
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        background-color: darkblue
        }
    tr.oddrow {
        background-color: white;
        }
</style>

<script>
    var milesDriven;
    var gallonsUsed;
    var mpg;
    var anyMore;

    document.writeln("<table>");
    document.writeln("<thead><tr><th>Miles Driven</th>");
    document.writeln("<th>Gallons Used</th>");
    document.writeln("<th>MPG</th>");
    document.writeln("</tr></thead><tbody>");

    while (anyMore == true) {
        milesDriven = window.prompt("How many miles did you drive?");
        gallonsUsed = window.prompt("How many gallons did you use?");
        mpg = milesDrive/gallonsUsed;
        document.writln("<tr><td>" + milesDriven + "</td><td>" + 
            gallonsUsed + "</td><td>" + mpg + "</td></tr>");

        anymore = confirm("Do you have any more data to input?");
    }
    document.writeln("</tbody></table>");

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in the approach. You should not use `document.writeln()` to modify document content. Instead, create elements and add them to the document tree. A good JavaScript tutorial should tell you how to do that. It will also explain that identifiers are case-sensitive, so you can’t just write `anyMore` here and `anymore` there. You also have other typos in identifiers. And since an undefined value does not equal `true`, your loop is not executed ever.

Comment: Thanks, I think the typos occurred after re-writing the script and blah. I've got it working now. Regarding using document.writeln vs elements: that is exactly what I thought (have done in the past, but way long ago), but we're actually being told, in this class, to utilize document.writeln(), stupid, right?

Comment: Also, the book we're using is Deitel's 5th Edition Internet and World Wide Web and it's first few chapters on js use document.writeln. arghhhhh

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mileage Record</title>
<style type = "text/css">
    table {
        width:300px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        background-color:lightblue;
        }
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 4px;
        }
    th {
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        background-color: darkblue
        }
    tr.oddrow {
        background-color: white;
        }
</style>

<script>
   // var milesDriven;
  //  var gallonsUsed;
  //  var mpg;
    var anyMore=0;
    var str="<table>";
        str+="<thead><tr><th>Miles Driven</th>";
        str+="<th>Gallons Used</th>";
        str+="<th>MPG</th>";
        str+="</tr></thead><tbody>";


function milesDriven(){
  return window.prompt("How many miles did you drive?");
}

function gallonsUsed(){
  return window.prompt("How many gallons did you use?");
}

function mpg(){
 return milesDriven()/gallonsUsed();
}


function addComponentsToDOM(){
    while (anyMore<3) { //not 0 is true or not undefined is true or not null is true 
    str+="<tr><td>" + milesDriven() + "</td><td>" + 
            gallonsUsed() + "</td><td>" + mpg() + "</td></tr>"
      //  anymore = confirm("Do you have any more data to input?");
      anyMore++;
    }

    str+="</tbody></table>";
    //document.writeln(); i suggest you not use this method add component to DOM tree
    //because  this method first empty DOM tree content
     document.body.innerHTML=str;
 }


//why use this event,because window after  loaded document.body not null
 window.onload=addComponentsToDOM;


</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: my QQ account 243030330,i am from china